# Append View to existing View

Tags: view, laravel, laravel-blade

In Laravel 4, I want to be able to append a fresh view to an existing view, by accessing a link or button. How am I supposed to do that? thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about nesting of views? Also, clarify `by accessing a link or button` and show your current code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Maybe I am not familiar with nesting views, but what I wish is to append a new view to an existing view when I press a link or button. More precisely both views will render only when a button is pressed. Until then, only the master view will render. My code is just plain and simple and both views will render even if I don't press the link. I use @include in the master view. I don't know what to show because this is not doing what I want. It's just a theory for me.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely want to use ajax, make an ajax request, set the action to the route which renders the appended view. Make a div in your parent view with id "appended" then on ajax success set the contents of the appended div to the data which you received from the ajax request, it solves your idea...  But id not recommend the idea itself, its not easy to control the structure of the pages with such method...  Better solution is to have a master view which yields the other views, if you already have a master view then create a sub master view

Answer (score 1):

After digging into nested views of Laravel 4, I have managed to do what I wanted. It's not such a big deal after all. In the controller I have done this

```
 $selected_char = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->character()->where('char_name', '=', $character)->first();  
 $title_list = Character::find($selected_char->id)->title()->get();
 $data = array();
                $data['title_list'] = $title_list;
            return View::make('layout.profile')
                    ->nest('title_details', 'layout.titledetail', $data);
```

The third parameter of the nest method must be an array. You can then access the information in the child view with

titledetail.blade.php

```
 @section('title-content')          

    @foreach($title_list as $t)

     <div class="infocontainer"> 
        <br> {{$t->char_title}} of {{$t->title_name}} {{$t->title}}                     

     </div>

    @endforeach

    @endsection
```

What I have done here is that I created a new div named "infocontainer" for each record my object holds. You don't have to do this.
In the master view you go specifically to the div you wish to put the child view in and yield the child view there:

```
<div class="example">
 @yield('title-content')
</div>
```

You don't even need to @include('title-content') just yield it in the specified div
You can even send additional variables from the controller

```
return View::make('layout.profile')
                    ->nest('title_details', 'layout.titledetail', $data)
                    ->with('example_var1', $example_var1)
                    ->with('example_var1', $example_var1)
```

or even nest additional views.

```
  return View::make('layout.profile')
                    ->nest('title_details', 'layout.titledetail', $data)
                    ->nest('add_title_details', 'layout.addtitledetails', $data)
```

Don't forget to put the additional variables for the new nested view in the $data array. This is a case when you want to, let's say, render a second nested view by accessing a link, or pressing a button from the first nested view.

And this is pretty much it. I even started doing this with Javascript. But no, what you have is very powerful. I hope this helps as it helped me.